# It's possible make a cross domain request from backbone js?

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, cross-domain

I have a backbone-js app, and i need make requests to the backend api but it's a different app which serves the backbone app.

In other words, i have a classic mvc app (app #1) that have all the backbone js files.

The backbone app (app #2) needs to make fetch (requests) to the backend api (app #3).

But i'm having an error like this in the bacbone app:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://foo ... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I tried to add that header to the response but still not working.

Is there a way to allow the cross domain request or i'll have to make the requests from backbone to app #1 and then the app #1 make the same request to the backend (app #3)?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Adding the header should solve your problem. What value did you add against the header in response add * or add the domain from which you are firing fetch call

Comment: Fixed. Adding the * on the header and enabling the OPTIONS request method fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) is a good flowchart  which explains how CORS works. May be this will help understand you more?

Comment: Very clear. Thanks!